# Benchmark to compare Git branches in Java?

Tags: java, git, testing, branch, benchmarking

Is there any good software to benchmark different Git branches? Or other way to approach it?

I have some original branch that I want to compare to, then I create a new branch and make some changes in the code design. Now I want to test to see if the code is faster or uses less memory. I would be running the exact same run configuration on both. The code I'm writing in Java in Eclipse. However, the solution I'm imagining might not be Java specific.

Does anyone know what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Other than: checkout branch1, build, run test, save results; checkout branch2, build, run test, save results; compare results?

Answer (score 2):

When I do this with Guava, I use [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com), which is very good at Java benchmarking, and knows how to deal with the JIT warmup time and everything.  (Its memory-measurement tools aren't working very well at the moment, but I hear the 1.0 release soonish will have that.)  Just run the Caliper benchmark on each branch; it'll output pleasant bar graphs to a web page you can experiment with to view the data in different ways.

http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/run/wasserman.louis@gmail.com/com.google.common.math.Log10Benchmark is a recent example of one I did, optimizing `IntMath.log10(int, RoundingMode)` in Guava.